# RewriteRule checking file in rewriten file path exists

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, caching

How can you use ModRewrite to check if a cache file exists, and if it does, rewrite to the cache file and otherwise rewrite to a dynamic file.

For example I have the following folder structure:

```
pages.php
cache/
  pages/
   1.html
   2.html
   textToo.html
   etc.
```

How would you setup the RewriteRules for this so request can be send like this:

```
example.com/pages/1
```

And if the cache file exists rewrite tot the cache file, and if the cache file does not exists, rewrite to pages.php?p=1

It should be something like this: (note that this does not work, otherwise I would not have asked this)

```
RewriteRule ^pages/([^/\.]+) cache/pages/$1.html [NC,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [NC] 
RewriteRule cache/pages/([^/\.]+).html pages.php?p=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

I can off coarse do this using PHP but I thought it had to be possible using mod_rewrite.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^pages/([^/\.]+) cache/pages/$1.html [NC,QSA]

# At this point, we would have already re-written pages/4 to cache/pages/4.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

# If the above RewriteCond succeeded, we don't have a cache, so rewrite to 
# the pages.php URI, otherwise we fall off the end and go with the
# cache/pages/4.html
RewriteRule ^cache/pages/([^/\.]+).html pages.php?p=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Turning off MultiViews is crucial (if you have them enabled) as well.

```
Options -MultiViews
```

Otherwise the initial request (/pages/...) will get automatically converted to /pages.php before mod_rewrite kicks in.  You can also just rename pages.php to something else (and update the last rewrite rule as well) to avoid the MultiViews conflict.

Edit: I initially included `RewriteCond ... !-d` but it is extraneous.

Answer (score 6):

Another approach would be to first look if there is a chached representation available:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/$0 -f
RewriteRule ^pages/[^/\.]+$ cache/$0.html [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^pages/([^/\.]+)$ pages.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

To generalize the question: insert this above the rule that should not be matched if the file exists.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

Sean Bright's answer provides a nice worked example for the caching question, but this line works more broadly. In my case, I have a link shortener where people can choose custom URLs and I didn't want it to be able to override existing files such as `favicon.ico`. Adding this line before the rewriterule fixed that issue.