# Ultimate mobile .htaccess redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mobile

I've got a decent working solution to mobile/desktop redirection in place using .htaccess code below, but there are a few more enhancements that could really make it ultimate if anyone can help.

Directory setup:

- desktop site: website.com
- mobile site: m.website.com

Cookie enabled links:

- going from desktop site to mobile site, set cookie to stay on mobile: http://m.website.com?m=1
- going from mobile site to desktop site, set cookie to stay on desktop: http://www.website.com?m=0

Current .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on

# Check if this is the desktop to mobile query string
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)m=1(&|$)

# Set a cookie, and skip the next 2 rules 
RewriteRule ^ - [CO=mredir:1:%{HTTP_HOST},S=2]

# Check if this is the mobile to desktop query string
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)m=0(&|$)

# Set a cookie, and skip the next rule
RewriteRule ^ - [CO=mredir:0:%{HTTP_HOST},S]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]

# Check if we're not already on the mobile site
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^m\.

# Can not read and write cookie in same request, must duplicate condition
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)m=0(&|$) 

# Check to make sure we haven't set the cookie before
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*mredir=0.*$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://m.website.com/ [L,R=302]
```

Things I'm looking to add:

1. If we're going to desktop version, either from mobile or just a normal desktop visit, make sure it always adds www.
2. For desktop to mobile redirection, direct to matching mobile page, but if it doesn't exist default to mobile home.  (Example: if you visit website.com/chairs on your mobile it will try to redirect to m.website.com/chairs, but if it doesn't exist it will instead redirect to m.website.com.  I think mapping would be something like ^(.*)$ http://m.website.com/$1, but not sure how to implement fallback to home page

Also, if anyone notices any errors or improvements in the current code would love to hear that as well!

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on

# Check if this is the desktop to mobile query string
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)m=1(&|$)

# Set a cookie, and skip the next 2 rules 
RewriteRule ^ - [CO=mredir:1:%{HTTP_HOST},S=2]

# Check if this is the mobile to desktop query string
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)m=0(&|$)

# Set a cookie, and skip the next rule
RewriteRule ^ - [CO=mredir:0:%{HTTP_HOST},S]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]

# Check if we're not already on the mobile site
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^m\.

# Can not read and write cookie in same request, must duplicate condition
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)m=0(&|$) 

# Check to make sure we haven't set the cookie before
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*mredir=0.*$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://m.website.com/ [L,R=302]

# 1.) Check if on desktop site and having www., if not redirect to www.website.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^m\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.website.com$1 [R=301,L]
```

2.) this cannot be done with mod_rewrite except "/chairs" is an existing file (and I guess it's not). So I would check it with your desired scripting language - e.g. in php:

```
if (!pageexists($_GET['page']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'm.website.com')
  header("Location: http://m.website.com/");
```

where pageexists() is a function you define to check if there is content for this page in mobile version.

Comment: I saw this posted on another question regarding fallback redirects, do you think something like this could work for #2? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/667284/htaccess-redirect-if-file-doesnt-exist             `RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}web/$0 !-f
RewriteRule ^process/[^/]+$ web/process/default.php [L]`

Comment: I think this could work, if "/chairs" is a real file in your webroot. You could then add a rule that checks, if this file exists in mobile webroot too and redirect to homepage if not.

Comment: Are you not yet satisfied with my reply? Please tell me what you are missing or consider to accept it - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge\ |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera\ m(ob|in)i|palm(\ os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows\ (ce|phone)|xda|xiino [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a\ wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|-m|r\ |s\ )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw-(n|u)|c55/|capi|ccwa|cdm-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(-|*)|g1\ u|g560|gene|gf-5|g-mo|go(.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd-(m|p|t)|hei-|hi(pt|ta)|hp(\ i|ip)|hs-c|ht(c(-|\ |*|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac(\ |-|/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt(\ |/)|klon|kpt\ |kwc-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg(\ g|/(k|l|u)|50|54|-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1-w|m3ga|m50/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(-|\ |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v\ )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt-g|qa-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|-[2-7]|i-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h-|oo|p-)|sdk/|se(c(-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh-|shar|sie(-|m)|sk-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h-|v-|v\ )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl-|tdg-|tel(i|m)|tim-|t-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m-|m3|m5)|tx-9|up(.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(-|\ )|webc|whit|wi(g\ |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas-|your|zeto|zte-) [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://detectmobilebrowser.com/mobile [R,L]