# .htaccess rule to redirect if file does not exists

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Application resides here: `http://localhost/reports/`

- reports

  - index.php
  - daily_stats.php
  - controllers

    - daily_stats.php //is a controller having br() as action

I want to write a .htaccess rule as per the foll cases:

```
case1: http://localhost/reports/daily_stats/  
           resulting url: http://localhost/reports/daily_stats.php

case2: http://localhost/reports/daily_stats/br/  
           resulting url: http://localhost/reports/index.php/daily_stats/br
```

where index.php take cares of routing to contoller

I have written the foll:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /reports/index.php/$1
```

Problem faced is when i enter `http://localhost/reports/daily_stats/br/`  it executes the daily_stats.php in the root folder rather the controller

when it see the server variable its like this:

```
[SCRIPT_FILENAME] => /var/www/reports/daily_stats.php
[QUERY_STRING] => 
[REQUEST_URI] => /reports/daily_stats/br
[SCRIPT_NAME] => /reports/daily_stats.php
[PATH_INFO] => /br
[PATH_TRANSLATED] => /var/www/br
[PHP_SELF] => /reports/daily_stats.php/br
```

should hv been this:
    [SCRIPT_FILENAME] => /var/www/reports/index.php
    [QUERY_STRING] => 
    [REQUEST_URI] => /reports/daily_stats/br
    [SCRIPT_NAME] => /reports/index.php
    [PATH_INFO] => /daily_stats/br
    [PATH_TRANSLATED] => /var/www/daily_stats/br
    [PHP_SELF] => /reports/index.php/daily_stats/br

The rewrite log says:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Aug/2012:15:22:30 +051800] [localhost/sid#b63fead8][rid#b6ae6058/subreq] (3) [perdir /var/www/reports/] add path info postfix: /var/www/reports/daily_stats.php -> /var/www/reports/daily_stats.php/br
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Aug/2012:15:22:30 +051800] [localhost/sid#b63fead8][rid#b6ae6058/subreq] (3) [perdir /var/www/reports/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/reports/daily_stats.php/br -> daily_stats.php/br
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Aug/2012:15:22:30 +051800] [localhost/sid#b63fead8][rid#b6ae6058/subreq] (3) [perdir /var/www/reports/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'daily_stats.php/br'
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Aug/2012:15:22:30 +051800] [localhost/sid#b63fead8][rid#b6ae6058/subreq] (4) [perdir /var/www/reports/] RewriteCond: input='/var/www/reports/daily_stats.php' pattern='!-f' => not-matched
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Aug/2012:15:22:30 +051800] [localhost/sid#b63fead8][rid#b6ae6058/subreq] (1) [perdir /var/www/reports/] pass through /var/www/reports/daily_stats.php
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Aug/2012:15:22:30 +051800] [localhost/sid#b63fead8][rid#b6af0058/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/reports/] add path info postfix: /var/www/reports/daily_stats.php -> /var/www/reports/daily_stats.php/br
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Aug/2012:15:22:30 +051800] [localhost/sid#b63fead8][rid#b6af0058/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/reports/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/reports/daily_stats.php/br -> daily_stats.php/br
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Aug/2012:15:22:30 +051800] [localhost/sid#b63fead8][rid#b6af0058/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/reports/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'daily_stats.php/br'
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Aug/2012:15:22:30 +051800] [localhost/sid#b63fead8][rid#b6af0058/initial] (4) [perdir /var/www/reports/] RewriteCond: input='/var/www/reports/daily_stats.php' pattern='!-f' => not-matched
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Aug/2012:15:22:30 +051800] [localhost/sid#b63fead8][rid#b6af0058/initial] (1) [perdir /var/www/reports/] pass through /var/www/reports/daily_stats.php
```

Comment: This should lead you on the right path: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/667284/htaccess-redirect-if-file-doesnt-exist

Comment: What's wrong with `ErrorDocument 404 /404.php` ?

Comment: Have you enabled re-write logs and if so what does it say?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've already written the rule for case1 ... but you need to block the rule from applying when the URL does not end at "daily_stats".  To do this, just add an `$` to the end of your match string.  Something like this should work:

```
RewriteRule ^reports/daily_stats/?$ /reports/daily_stats.php
```