# mod_rewrite: Redirect to cache or script

Tags: php, apache, caching, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm having some troubles with my mod_rewrite configuration, for a "cache" solution that I'm working on. I have directory called "cache" with compiled html files. I also have an index.php file which handles all the requests.

Right now all requests are rewritten to the index.php file like: "/articles" => index.php?q=articles.

But now I want it to rewrite to "cache/articles/index.html" if it exists, or else just fall back and rewrite to the index.php script.

I have messed around with the rewrite for a while know, but I can't get it to work. The rewrite code looks like this now (without anything for the cache):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What errors are you getting? Can you explain "not working"? Anything in your Apache error logs? Can you post the .htaccess code you tried for the cache?

Comment: What's your specific problem in adding the cache? At which point you don't know any further? Which request-url file-name sheme is your cache using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [RewriteRule checking file in rewriten file path exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/470880/rewriterule-checking-file-in-rewriten-file-path-exists)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following to the `.htaccess` file in the root directory of your site.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase / 

#if the index.html exists in the cache
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache%{REQUEST_URI}/index.html -f [NC] 
#then display it
RewriteRule ^ cache%{REQUEST_URI}/index.html [L]

#other existing rules go here
```