# rewrite for almost everything under /

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'd like to add groups to my site, and for that I would like to get rid of a directory, thus the homepage of each group would be like: http://example.org/my-awesome-group instead of http://example.org/group/my-not-so-awesome-group

using the rule RewriteRule ^group/([a-z0-9-]+)/  is quite easy to rewrite each requests accordingly, but without it I'm having some headaches, I'm not sure how to tackle this. do you have any experience about it?

for example there's no group /javascript /css those have to be treated as actual directories on the file system.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make rewriting rules conditional on whether or not the request refers to a file/directory that actually exists on the filesystem.  In addition to the [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) documentation, take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470880/rewriterule-checking-file-in-rewriten-file-path-exists) here on SO that has an example configuration.