# htaccess get filename without path

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to get the requested **filename without the path** with htaccess for a RewriteCond.
`REQUEST_FILENAME` returns the full absolute path, but I only need the filename like *test.php*

I've been searching for this a lot but couldn't find anything that helped me out.
Thanks for any responses in advance!

**Edit:**

Im trying to do something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond _%{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ _$1.php [L]
```

- The URL typed in the browser looks like this: http://example.org/test
- The File that will be requestested by the RewriteRule is: http://example.org/_test.php
- With `RewriteCond _%{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f` i tried to check **if the file exists** first

**Basically I want to do this:**

URI: */test/blah*
Check if _*test.php* exists (with underscore!)

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/470880/rewriterule-checking-file-in-rewriten-file-path-exists

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/_$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ _$1.php [L]
```

I changed `*` to `+` so requests for e.g. example.com/ will not redirect to `_.php`