# htaccess get file and extension without path

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have tried to figure this out for very long but still cant. I have tried [htaccess get filename without path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10835848/htaccess-get-filename-without-path) but it doesn't work for me.

Here is my directory

```
/www
|-- /other.org
|-- /example.com
    |-- /sub 
        |-- .htaccess
        |-- success.html
        |-- /imgs
            |-- photo.png
```

I am trying to find if an image exists in http://example.com/sub/imgs when there is a request for that image or file at http://example.com/sub. If it exists, then user will be redirected to success.html. But I cannot do that.

For example if I type into the browser

```
http://example.com/sub/photo.png
```

It checks if the file photo.png or any kind of image exists in /sub/imgs/photo.png, it does not exist and should not exist in /sub directory.

```
http://example.com/sub/imgs/photo.png
```

The redirected output will be success.html if it exists.

```
http://example.com/sub/success.html
```

I  tried

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/sub%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule (.*)\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png)$ success.html
```

but the `%{REQUEST_URI}` is `/sub/photo.png` so the output will be `http://example.com/sub/imgs/sub/photo.png`. There isn't any request that can get the file name or anything after the last slash (/). Is it possible to get just the file name `photo.png` so I can just do:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/sub/imgs%{FILE_NAME} -f
RewriteRule (.*)\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png)$ success.html
```

Is there any way to get this working?

Comment: `RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/sub/imgs/$1 -f
    RewriteRule ^.+/(.+\.jpeg?|png|gif)$ /redirect.html [L]`

Comment: @starkeen hi it doesn't work for me, I edited the question to fix some directory errors. i think the way I entered the directories were wrong just now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this rule in `sub/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /sub/

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/sub/imgs/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^(.+\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif|tiff|ico))$ success.html [L,NC]
```

Comment: Hi, can you breakdown to me what the last line does? The `(.+\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif|tiff|ico))`

Comment: Last line matches any image name that ends with any of these extensions `jpe?g|png|gif|tiff|ico`. `(?:..)` is called non-capturing group

Comment: Thanks! I read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group but still don't understand what is it used for here?

Comment: We could also use `(jpe?g|png|gif|tiff|ico)` in this rule but that is called a capturing group as it puts image extension in `$2. However here we don't want to capture it so using a non-capturing group.

Comment: May I know what happens if we use a capture group here and how is it done? I changed the html to php and readfile an image but the image doesn't display, instead it displays the gremlins, not sure why this happened or how to fix it. I have already put the Content type header.

Comment: @pleasega: I suggest opening a new question for image display issue with more details.