# Remove extensions for both .html and .php in apache

Tags: php, html, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

The code is mixed to I have .html and .php in the same folder.  There is never a time there there is the same name but different extensions. I have some code that should work but doesn't. The html part works but when I try to request a PHP page without an extension the URL it gives a 404

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -F
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -F
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Comment: You are likely never getting past the first set of conditions in your .htaccess file. There is no way for Apache to know whether it should be looking for a html file or a php file given the conditions you have stated.

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem. I don't know how to skip the first rule if the cond is false.

Comment: Try changing the upper case -F's to lower case -f instead. Also check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470880/rewriterule-checking-file-in-rewriten-file-path-exists)

Comment: @Dave i've tried with lowercase -f and it still didn't work and i do have multiviews off

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this on the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.html [L]
```